# Duplicate Row Sum

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to combine duplicated rows in a table while summing the numbers in the last column, then creating a new summarized table below.

Only the first duplicated row is being summed. This value then appears in all of the rows below.

Example Table - five Columns
[image]

```vb
Sub CombineDupesV3()
    
    Dim x       As Long
    Dim r       As Long
    Dim arr()   As Variant
    Dim dic     As Object
    Const DELIM As String = "|"
    
    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    x = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    arr = Cells(1, 1).Resize(x, 5).Value
    
   
    For x = LBound(arr, 1) + 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        
        If dic.exists(arr(x, 1)) Then
            arr(x, 5) = arr(x, 5) + CDbl(Split(dic(arr(x, 1)), DELIM)(3))
            
        Else
            dic(arr(x, 1)) = arr(x, 2) & DELIM & arr(x, 3) & DELIM & arr(x, 4) & DELIM & arr(x, 5)
        End If
        dic(arr(x, 1)) = arr(x, 2) & DELIM & arr(x, 3) & DELIM & arr(x, 4) & DELIM & arr(x, 5)
        
        Debug.Print "X = " & x
    Next x
    
    
    r = UBound(arr, 1) + 2
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Cells(r, 1).Resize(, 5).Value = Cells(1, 1).Resize(, 5).Value
    
    r = r + 1
    
        
     For x = 0 To dic.Count - 1
        Cells(r + x, 1).Value = dic.keys()(x)
        Cells(r + x, 2).Resize(, 4).Value = Split(dic.items()(x), DELIM)
        Cells(r + x, 5).Value = CDbl(Cells(r, 5).Value)
        
        Debug.Print "R = " & r
    Next x
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    
    Erase arr
    Set dic = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Posted a late answer to your question; feel free to accept by ticking the green checkmark if helpful :-)

Answer (score 0):

The conversion line in the last loop should address the correct row value `r + x`

```
For x = 0 To dic.Count - 1
    Cells(r + x, 1).Value = dic.keys()(x)
    Cells(r + x, 2).Resize(, 4).Value = Split(dic.items()(x), DELIM)
    '>> convert string to double <<
    Cells(r + x, 5).Value = CDbl(Cells(r + x, 5).Value)
Next x
```

Further hints:

Try to fully qualify all range references in order to avoid unwanted results as unqualified cell addresses refer to the active sheet by default which needn't be the one you have in mind :-)

You should either redefine the data range definition or the target range as they might conflict if you run code twice.